# Magento 2 : How to set multiple currencies in one storefront?

Tags: magento2, multicurrency

Magento 2, how to set multiple currency supports for one store.
I want to display currency in header of site.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you activated these currencies in magento backend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To setup multiple currency on Magento 2 follow this step:

1. Setup currency: Move to menu **Stores** >> **Configuration**. Under **GENERAL** tab you will find sub menu **Currency Setup**. Setup **Currency Options** with what you need and click **Save Config**.
   [image]
2. Setup currency rates: Move menu to **Stores** >> **Currency Rates**. Set value for all parameters and hit **Saves Currency Rates**

[image]

Thats all, you will see dropdown on you front.

[image]

Comment: I have followed the above steps but No luck on Magento version 2.3.3 @Dadang Sasmita

Comment: For me also. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 7):

After config the currency, you want to show in a drop down list. You also have to setup the exchange rate. **stores > currency rates**. Seem we could only have one base currency per **website**. That means the currency switch in the front will only change price accordingly for **display purpose only**. The actual amount customers to paid is still calculated in **base currency**. Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to STORES > CONFIGURATION > Currency Setup choose Allowed Currencies you want to display
   Choose base and display currency in there. Save before leave
2. STORES > Currency Rates and allow all currency in there